# Removing IMAP Folders

Tags: email, gmail, android, imap

In my gmail account I have hidden the [IMAP]/Archive, [IMAP]/Drafts labels using the web interface. 
I've also removed any labels to these folders from any emails I have.

The problem is that I still have these folders on hy Android phone and tablet.  Is there any way of getting rid of these folders?  I would have thought that since they are not used, they might go away on the next sync but unfortunately they don't :(

Anyone managed to do this?

Comment: The simplest way would be disconnect the mobile device ( i.e. clear the email client's cache ) and reconnecting it.  This assumes you have deleted or hidden the labels in question.  You don't mention which client your using, some clients, won't respect the hidden status and will display all labels for your convenience.

Comment: I'm using the android gmail client.  I cleared out the data and let it resync but the folders reappeared.  I would have hoped the gmail client would respect the hidden status though.

Comment: If you don't use them, why haven't you deleted them?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking in ever-so slightly the wrong place (I did exactly this last week)

Gmail's settings let you show/hide labels as you mention - but that's just for the UI, over to the right there is the 'show in IMAP' checkbox that lets you control if, say, your phone can see it.

[image]

Comment: I tried this some time ago unfortunately the phone gmail app didn't get rid of them on a sync :(